# Print the number of cpus in use per job in slurm?

Tags: slurm

We have switched to using slurm from sge for our cluster job queuing system. In sge when you used the `qstat` function it printed the number of cpus/slots in use per job - is there a simple way to do this in slurm? `squeue` only shows the number of nodes used per job. Thanks.

```
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           1981      q      run-01     root  R      16:21      1 node001
           1982      q      run-02     root  R      16:21      1 node002
           1983      q      run-03     root  R      16:21      1 node003
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `squeue` command has two parameters that allow choosing the columns displayed in the output `--format` and `--Format`. Each have an option (respectively `%c`  and `NumCPUs`) to display the number of cores requested by the job.

Try with

```
squeue -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R %c"
```

This will show the default columns and add the number of cores as the last column. You can fiddle with the format string to arrange the columns as you want. Then, when you are happy with the output, you can set it as the value of the `SQUEUE_FORMAT` variable in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

```
export SQUEUE_FORMAT='%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R %c'
```

See the [squeue man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html#OPT_format=%3Coutput_format%3E) for more details.